# prevent file collision PHP with Matlab

Tags: php, mysql, matlab

i have php file that run from cmd matlab function -> that function is create .txt file and fill it up with the analysis results. then the php file takes this .txt file and sending the information as a string(lines from .txt) to a database (phpmyadmin). 
my problem is that the php start to send the info from the .txt while the matlab is still writing to the file. 
i thought to solve it with a global var that matlab and php know him, and use it as a flag that Flag determines when Matlab finished building the necessary file. i thought to use the window registry, but it is very complicated. there is any easier way?

thanks alot,
doron

my php file:

```
 unlink('test.txt');
 if(isset($_POST['filepath'])) {
  $filename  = $_POST['filepath'];
  $inputDir  = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\login";
  $outputDir = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\login";

  // here php open the matlab function from the cmd:

  $command = "matlab -sd ".$inputDir." -r phpcreatefile2('".$outputDir."\\".$filename.".txt')";
  exec($command);

  $fileLoc= "".$outputDir."\\".$filename.".txt" ;
  echo $fileLoc ;
  echo "The following command was run: ".$command."<br/>";
  echo $filename." was created in ".$outputDir."<br/>";
  echo " Now the txt file will write in the DB <br/>";
```

// here i tried to check if the file exists and if it is not empty. but its not working  because matlab still writing to the file.

```
 while (1) {

       if (file_exists("test.txt") ){
       echo "check1";
       if (filesize("test.txt")!= 0) {
       echo "check2";
       $file = file('test.txt');
       $sql = "INSERT INTO `ID_5525_Medical_record`(`Data`,`AV_Power`,`Highest_Amp`,`90BW`,`Url_figure`) VALUES ('$file[0]','$file[1]','$file[2]','$file[3]','$file[4]')" ;
        if(mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
        {
        unlink('test.txt');
        echo "the txt file is now in the DB <br/>";
         }
         break;
        }
        else {
        echo "i am going to sleep";
        sleep(1);
        echo "i am awake";
        }
        }
     }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Normally, using COM would be the proper way to implement inter process communication between php and MATLAB (Or maybe some alternative, think all are sufficient for this simple task).

Here it seems you call MATLAB only one, you can fix the behaviour appending `-wait` to the command. This forces launcher to stay open until matlab closes, blocking your PHP-Script at `exec($command);`. Big disadvantage is, that you have to start Matlab for every function call and close it afterwards. With com one instance can stay open and do everything.